# How to use Simple XML to handle Line Feeds (LF)?

Tags: php, xml, line-breaks

i am using simple-xml to parse some xml-Data that we get from "outside".

The XML comes the follwing way:

```
<element>
  <address>Name of the Customer
Street No.
ZIP City</adress>
</element>
```

Every line break is done with a LF.

So if i just do something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

echo $xml->element['address'];
```

it will just echo all the adress out in one line:

```
Output: Name of the Customer Street No. ZIP City
```

I've no possibility to change the xml (like [!CDATA..] or the like), because it is not generated by us.

Is there a way to parse the line breaks for proper output?

Any help is appreciated, because i - once again (:P) - have no idea what to do.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test :

```
echo nl2br( $xml->element['address'] ) ;
```

Comment: Your problem depends on your output (HTML, plain text, etc). Consider using str_replace too. It's used to replace characters/strings in other strings.